# Setting an environment variable in Ansible from a command output of bash command

Tags: bash, environment-variables, ansible

I would like to set output of a shell command as an environment variable in Ansible.

I did the following to achieve it:

```
- name: Copy content of config.json into variable
  shell:  /bin/bash -l -c "cat /storage/config.json"
  register: copy_config
  tags: something

- name: set config
  shell: "echo $TEMP_CONFIG"
  environment:
    TEMP_CONFIG: "{{copy_config}}"
  tags: something
```

But somehow after the ansible run, when I do run the following command:

```
echo ${TEMP_CONFIG}
```

in my terminal it gives an empty result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are at least two problems:

1. You should pass `copy_config.stdout` as a variable

   ```
   - name: set config
     shell: "echo $TEMP_CONFIG"
     environment:
       TEMP_CONFIG: "{{copy_config.stdout}}"
     tags: something
   ```
2. You need to register the results of the above task and then again print the `stdout`, so:

   ```
   - name: set config
     shell: "echo $TEMP_CONFIG"
     environment:
       TEMP_CONFIG: "{{copy_config.stdout}}"
     tags: something
     register: shell_echo

   - debug:
       var: shell_echo.stdout
   ```
3. You never will be able to pass the variable to a non-related process this way. So unless you registered the results in an rc-file (like `~/.bash_profile` which is sourced on interactive login if you use Bash) no other shell process would be able to see the value of `TEMP_CONFIG`. This is how system works.

Comment: thanks a lot for the prompt answer, I have question with respect to point 2 and 3, why do I need to register it and echo out the std.out? what's the purpose of it? I thought doing `environment:
    TEMP_CONFIG: "{{copy_config.stdout}}"` will add this into the .bash_profile file, why do I need to explicitly add it?

Comment: You need to reference `stdout` subkey, because that's where Ansible stores the stdout of the command. No, it won't add anything to `.bash_profile`, it just sets the environment for the command specified in the module.